# Cotinus coggygria for fire?

Tags: shrubs

I am going to cut my old Smoke bush (*Cotinus coggygria*). I nave noticed, that it smells nice, similar to eucalyptus. Would it be possible to use it's wood for a fire during winter, which may be not coming now, but next winter season, when enough days have passed?

Thanks

Comment: Very good question. We have _italicised_the scientific name for you. Thank you for your question.

Comment: Be careful burning anything that contains a lot of volatile oils. I once put a heap of *mahonia* prunings on a bonfire. Ten seconds later I had a firework display of burning mahonia leaves flying into the air and blowing around in the wind before they landed. No serious damage done, but that was NOT fun.